# Mixed data in excel

Tags: excel

I have over 40.000 products that I need to work with. All of these products have unique attributes, which I want to sort into columns. All the attributes separated with a colon (attribute group: attribute), however these are mixed. There are more than 1000 different attribute groups.

I can do it with nested `IF`, but thats too many.

For example `=IF(LEFT(D3;4)="Size";D3;IF(LEFT(D3;4)=Size;E3;""))`

[image: This is what I mean]

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this formula. adjust it to your needs. Formula is looking at attributes stated in column names, then uses partial match to sort values in each row.

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX($B2:$H2,1,MATCH(B$8&"*",$B2:$H2,0)),IF(B$8="Price",INDEX($B2:$H2,1,MATCH(SUM($B2:$H2),$B2:$H2,0)),"")),"")
```

[image]